# android remove touch to beam ui for 4.1.2

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I searched StackOverflow and XDA-Developer but cannot find out the way to remove "touch to beam" UI/UX for the Samsung S3 I9305 device.

I also tried to create a sample foreground dispatch or Ndef message, but still need "touch to beam" UI/UX.

Here is what I want:

1. Remove "touch to beam" UI/UX
2. Touch another device without UI to start transfer data
3. Then another device receive data

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "remove touch to beam"? I don't get it. Please rephrase your entire question.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.1.2 does not provide any API to remove/bypass the Beam UI. Therefore, there is no way to do this on a regular Android system. Starting with Android 4.4 you could possibly achieve a similar effect by using the Reader Mode API on one device and HCE on the other.

**If you want to create your own modified Android version** you could, however, get rid of the Beam UI by modifying the source code of the Android NFC system service.

Similarly, **if the device is equipped with Xposed (or similar)**, you may be able to modify the behavior of the NFC system service to bypass the Beam UI.